# Get Google Analytics data using GAPI without login in

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-api-js-client

I have a news website and I have to show the "Top 5 most visited news of the day" using the data tracked with google analytics, but I haven't managed to make it work. Every code example I've found shows a pop up to login, as if he had his google account linked with the data in analytics, but obviously that's not the case.

I'm trying using this with JS, something like this

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js"></script>

...



<script>
    function start() {
      // 2. Initialize the JavaScript client library.
      gapi.client.load('analytics', 'v3').then(function() {
        gapi.client.init({
          'apiKey': 'SOME_API_KEY',
          'clientId': 'SOME_CLIENT_ID',
          'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
        }).then(function() {
            return gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
              'ids': 'ga:' + "SOME_ID",
              'start-date': 'yesterday',
              'end-date': 'today',
              'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
              'dimensions': 'ga:pagetitle',
              'max-results': '5',
              'sort': '-ga:pageviews,-ga:date'
            });
        }).then(function(response) {
          console.log(response  );
        }, function(reason) {
          console.log(reason)
          console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
        });
      });
    };
    gapi.load('client', start);
</script>
```

And I'm getting this response:

```
{result: {…}, body: "{↵  "error": {↵    "code": 401,↵    "message": "Re…project.",↵    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"↵  }↵}↵", headers: {…}, status: 401, statusText: null}
body
:
"{↵  "error": {↵    "code": 401,↵    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",↵    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"↵  }↵}↵"
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are able to use NodeJS. But if you use the [google-oauth-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-oauth-jwt) library or the [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) library. See [this link](http://2ality.com/2015/10/google-analytics-api.html) for an example tutorial for googleapis with NodeJS.

You need to use a key from the service account, so you need to create a service account. You could login with an access token, by using googleapis.auth.JWT, which needs your serviceaccount emailaddress, the private key and the scope ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']

I'll show you some example code from a project of mine:

**Googleapis library NodeJS (I'm using express and I used a promise in my routing to get the key, and google api data)**

```
var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
            '[your serviceaccount@emailaddress]',  
            path.join(__dirname, '../.', '/files/KEY.json'),//path to your json key file]
            null,
            ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'] //scope
        );

        jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
            console.log('jwtClient.authorize() started');

            //console.log(tokens);
            if (err) {
                console.log('error in authorization:' + err);
                return;
            } else {
                console.log('authorization success!');
                console.log(tokens);
                return tokens;
            }
        });



var VIEW_ID = 'ga:[yourviewid]';
    analytics.data.ga.get({
        'auth': jwtClient,
        'ids': VIEW_ID,
        'metrics': 'ga:uniquePageviews',
        'dimensions': 'ga:pagePath',
        'start-date': 'today',
        'end-date': 'today',
        'sort': '-ga:uniquePageviews',
        'max-results': 5,

    }, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
        return JSON.stringify(response, null, 4);
    });
```

**Example with routing and [Google-oauth-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-oauth-jwt) library**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var googleAuth = require('google-oauth-jwt');

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
      googleAuth.authenticate({
        email: 'yourserviceaccount@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
        // use the PEM file we generated from the downloaded key
        key: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMII [your big ass private key which can be obtained by using a file too.-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
        // specify the scopes you wish to access
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
        }, function (err, token) {
          res.json({token: token});
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can circumvent login with client-side code. The easiest workaround would be to create the table in Google Data Studio and then embed that on your site.